# How to create these complex matrices using NiceMatrix package?

Tags: nicematrix

I'm not very experienced with this package but I've tried many ways to reproduce this matrices below:

The most difficult for me is the traced line and the separated vector IV together in the same line

[image]

This one as well:

[image]

Comment: It would be great if you could  show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and hence much more likely that some one will try to help you. Section 17.5 of the `nicematrix` manual might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to construct the second matrix with `nicematrix`.

It's not possible to use a `{bNiceMatrix}` with the keys `first-row` and `first-col` because of the dotted rules that must extend outside the matrix.

That's why I use a `{NiceArray}` and add the brackets after the construction of the main array by using a `\SubMatrix` in the `\CodeAfter`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
$\begin{NiceArray}{rcccc:c:c}
      & V_j & V_{j'} & V_k & V_{k'} & I_1 & I_2 \\
  j   &     &        &     &        & 1   \\
  j'  &     &        &     &        & -1  \\
  k   &     &        &     &        &     & 1  \\
  k'  &     &        &     &        &     & -1 \\
  \hdottedline
  m+1 & 1   & -1     \\
  \hdottedline
  m+2 &     &        & 1   & -1     & -r 
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix[{2-2}{7-7}]
\end{NiceArray}$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]